# OpAmp with inputs connected together

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, noise

So I was taking a look at some of the example schematics in Eagle and I came upon this weird OpAmp configuration in which both inputs are connected:
[image: AmpOp with both inputs connected together]

I'm not sure what this is meant to do, my best guess is that this was done in order to stop the output from swinging due to both inputs being unconnected. Does anybody know if that is the case? And if so, why would that be a problem?
Also, there is something else that might be important: the same IC has another OpAmp which is being used as a comparator in this circuit.

Edit.
This is where the other OpAmp from the same IC is used.
[image: Circuit in which the other OpAmp is used]

Comment: This shouldn't be an op-amp anyway. It should be a compartor (it is being used as a comparator). Some comparator datasheets recommend tying all unused inputs to GND. My guess is that the part used in the actual PCB is a comparator not an op-amp. Whether this is correct needs to be investigated further by checking the BOM to see what part is really used. It sometimes happens that schematic part numbers are not correct or don't match the BOM. If the footprint is compatible, the update may be rolled out by changing the BOM only and leaving the schematic alone.

Comment: If the MEGA2560 is actually being built this way with this part, well, someone screwed up somewhere along the way. It shouldn't be done like this. But if it works then it works, so what else can you say? But if you design your own board, you may want to change IC5 to a comparator (may be able to do it with a simple part change).

Comment: I found [this](https://cdn-reichelt.de/bilder/web/xxl_ws/B300/ARDUINO_MEGA_A01.png) image of the MEGA2560 and it seems that they actually use the opamp in the schematic. You can't see the whole part code but the two last digits are "58", it's the IC just above the DC jack.

Comment: Could this be because of price or availability?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/WvW6Xwg) is another picture, this time showing the whole part number.

Comment: OK, seems like it really is an LM358. It is just a screw-up of some sort. They may have determined by testing that it works OK the way it is. I am not trying to second guess the designer. But it seems like it would be easier and better to just use an LM393 (which is open-collector). That would be the cheapest most available option, but then they would need a pullup resistor. But then, also, the unused part would be fine the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as you suspect.  An unused op-amp with inputs improperly connected.

From [How to Properly Configure Unused Operational Amplifiers](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf)

> Degradation Conditions
>
> Connecting the input pins together or to the supply rails can lead to device
>   damage. If configured like this, the input stage can suffer permanent electrical overstress (EOS) damage, as shown

[image]

It references [The Unused Op Amp—what to do?](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/archives/b/thesignal/archive/2012/11/27/the-unused-op-amp-what-to-do)

[image]

From [Application Design Guidelines for LM324/LM358 Devices](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa277/sloa277.pdf)

> 7.1 Do Not Connect Inputs Directly to Ground
>   For both used and unused amplifiers, the inputs must not be connected directly to ground or any other low impedance node. Always add some resistance to limit the current to less than 10 mA, regardless of any possible fault condition. All the input pins have a diode from the input to the device’s GND, or V–, pin. In
>   dual supply applications, the GND pin will be negative. However, during power up, power down, or supply faults, the GND pin may become positive. If this occurs then a grounded input pin will have potentially damaging current flow due to the input diode. Even if the GND pin is also grounded, such as in single supply applications, there is a possibility that the input ground will be negative relative to the op amp’s internal ground node. Ground differences occur when there is poor layout or high current transients, ∆i/∆t. Adding 1-kΩ to 10-kΩ series resistors to the input pin is acceptable in most applications.
>
> 7.2 Unused Amplifier Connections
>   Occasionally applications will not need all the amplifiers in a dual or quad package. The unused op amp should be connected in a way that is safe for the unused amplifier and doesn’t affect the used amplifiers. The best connection method puts the op amp into the normal linear operation range and no inputs are connected directly to low impedance nodes. The output of the op amp is not a low impedance node. The output by itself cannot provide a harmful voltage and/or current to the input. Therefore, no series resistor is needed between the input and output pins.

Answer (score 0):

The LM358D is a dual operational amplifier, with two op-amp circuits per chip. If an odd number of op amps is desired, then one unit might be unused; in that case it should not left floating since floating inputs can pick up noise from the surroundings, causing undesired power dissipation or inducing issues with the other unit on the chip.

Depending on the way the power rails are configured and the chip's behavior, connecting both inputs to ground might be the easiest way to keep that unit idle.

Given more of the schematic it would be possible to confirm this, or possibly suggest better ways of connecting that unused unit. TI also suggests other options for connecting unused units in [this TechNote](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf).

Edit: Given that this is an Arduino Mega, power is a single-ended supply rather than split-rail; since V- is within the recommended common-mode voltage for this part, this doesn't present a particular issue and is OK. There are other issues with the op-amp's other circuit, which are far more pressing than the configuration of the unused inputs to that op-amp chip. For example, the op-amp is being used as a comparator, without hysteresis, while a more suitable comparator chip could lead to a more robust and reliable design.

Comment: That's the schematic of the Arduino MEGA2560. I'll include the part of the schematic in which the other OpAmp is present on an edit

Answer (score 0):

The point of this circuit is exactly as you've deduced; to stop the op amp's output from being unpredictable. The LM358 chip has multiple op amps on it, so if you don't need all of them it's good practice to tie all inputs of the unused amplifiers to some fixed voltage, so they don't just pick up noise and amplify it.

Answer (score 0):

**If this op amp is powered by a single voltage supply**, connecting both inputs to a supply rail, as shown in your figure, is not a best practice. For reference, see Texas Instruments' [TechNote SBOA204A](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf) *How to Properly Configure Unused Operational Amplifiers* which states at the top of page 1:

> Connecting the input pins together or to the supply rails can lead to device damage. If configured like this, the input stage can suffer permanent electrical overstress (EOS) damage